# Duplicate packets in udp with multicast

Tags: java, udp, multicast

Here is my problem:
In the following example I receive duplicate packets, but only in my network and I don't understand why. The funny thing is that this only happens on my network, I've tried on 4 other networks and everything is ok. I've used Wireshark to track packets and it shows double packets.

Here is the code:

Server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ProvaServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(12000)) {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.3.5");
            Integer i = 1;
            while (true) {
                DatagramPacket msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(i.toString().getBytes(), i.toString().getBytes().length, address, 11000);
                socket.send(msgPacket);
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;

public class ProvaClient {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        try (MulticastSocket mcs = new MulticastSocket(11000)){
            mcs.setReuseAddress(true);
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.3.5");
            mcs.joinGroup(address);
            while (true) {
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                mcs.receive(msgPacket);
                String byteToString = new String(msgPacket.getData(),0, msgPacket.getLength(), "US-ASCII");
                System.out.println("Messaggio ricevuto: " + byteToString);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Messaggio ricevuto: 1
Messaggio ricevuto: 2
Messaggio ricevuto: 3
Messaggio ricevuto: 4
Messaggio ricevuto: 4
Messaggio ricevuto: 5
Messaggio ricevuto: 5
```

Comment: I ran your code. I do not get the same output as you. I do not have repeat message.

Comment: I know, it only happens on my network and I don't understand why

Comment: Try debugging your network using network tools. For hint, have a look at this. https://serverfault.com/questions/294207/how-can-i-test-multicast-udp-connectivity-between-two-servers

Comment: Yes.  You probably have a network configuration issue of some kind.  read this for some background on what can cause duplicate multicast packets: http://www.icir.org/fenner/mcast/dups.html

Comment: I noticed that with the cable it gives me problems, in wifi no.